# implementing a stack of commands for obtaining a transactional behaviour- Delphi

Tags: delphi, transactions, delphi-2009, command-pattern

I need to create a tool for performing complex scripts against a database.

For several resasons I cannot rely on DB transactional behaviour, but I need to implement my own transactional system.

The approach I am trying is with the help of the command pattern (my case is more complex, here I put a simplified version for discussion):

```
type
  IMyCommand = interface(IInterface)
    procedure Execute();
    procedure Undo();
  end;

type
  TSQLCommand = class (TInterfacedObject, IMyCommand)
  private
    FDBConnection: TDBConnection;
    FDBQuery: TDBQuery;
    FExecuteSQL: string;
    FUndoSQL: string;
    FExecuted: boolean; // set to True as the command has been executed
  public
    procedure Execute;
    procedure Undo;
    procedure Prepare(aExecuteSQL, aUndoSQL: string);
    constructor Create(aDBConnection: TDBConnection);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

I create a set of actions, for every action I will pass a "Execute" and "Undo" sql statement, examples:

A call to Prepare could be:

```
Prepare('INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (ID, DATA) VALUES (15, 'Hello')',// aExecuteSQL
'DELETE FROM TESTTABLE WHERE ID = 15'); //aUndoSQL
```

so somehow I am making very small changes (like inserting a single simple row, updating a single row, ...), for every change the "undo" is very obvious.

I will prepare a stack of command objects (using probably the TObjectStack collection), and call the Execute method one command at a time and as one is executed I will set FExecuted to True, and save the component to disk.

So what I whant to do is to run all the scripts, but I want to manage the cases in which something goes wrong.

If something goes wrong I would like to execute all the commands from last to first calling the Undo method. Of course before doing this I need to be able to restore from disk the components (in case the failure is an hardware failure, in case the failure is another reason I already have the stack in memory and I can easily call undo one command at a time).

Note: The main reason why I cannot rely on the DB transactional behaviour is that I need to insert also big blobs, and every blob is downloaded from internet and then inserted, so I cannot leave a transaction open for ever because I want to commit every small change to the db. What I do with blobs is download one, insert it, download next, insert it, ...

So my question is: could you suggest a way to persist to disk my objects? I have Delphi 2009, so one option is to make a TInterdacedPersistent and save the component to stream and then to file, anyway in this way I would have many files, with extra complicatinos, while I would prefer a single file. Could you suggest?

Edit: I realized TObjectStack is buggy in Delphi 2009 (Pop doesn't return a correct type), so the same can be done with TObjectStack.

Comment: Aside from allowing undo, transactions also allow other consumers of the database to see a consistent view of the data instead of getting half-updated records that may or may not contain references to the not-yet-downloaded blobs. Also, unless you're first reading the current record values, your `update` queries do *not* have obvious "undo" operations. I fear you're re-inventing transactions badly. You should first make absolutely sure that you can't just use long-running transactions or transactions with *checkpoints*.

Comment: INSERT from your example eventually could fire triggers which could change data in other tables. So, your DELETE will not undo your operation or will undo it partially. Another reason for transactions is preventing DIRTY READS which your mechanism will allow.

Comment: @Rob Yes good catch on update statements, I should read also the existing state. Yes somehow I am reinventing transactions, but the problem is that I have thos big blobs to insert into the db. one solution could also to download them all locally and only after they are all downloaded start a very big transaction.

Comment: @Andrei I am not writing a RDBMS engine, I am just handling a particular case in which I force all users to be offline before running it. SO the dirty reads problem is not there, for update I could find a solution, triggers are not there on the tables I am modifying. Anyway since my main concern is inserting large blobs, probably I should investigate how to manage a transaction in which I insert blobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a better approach than using a transaction, as Andrei K. mentioned your implementation is NOT safe, therefore using StartTransaction, Commit and Rollback is a MUST!

Comment: Ok finally I realized that I could simplify my life by using TMSConnection.BeginTransaction and TMSConnection.Commit (I am using devart components). In this way I don't need to use SQL transactions in a script, that was blocking me, because I couldn't insert blobs inside a single script, but now I solved the problem. Thanks for insisting on transaction, it made me find the solution.

Comment: oh-ho-ho so your using UniDAC?! why didn't you said so, I have a "framework" for that that in pseudo code would be like: a base class(child of TObject) which has the TransactionStart(BeginTransaction), TransactionCommit(Commit) and TransactionRollback(Rollback), for each table in the database I create a new descending class of the base class which has options like: SQL(const s: string), SQLFmt(const s: string; const args: array of const), etc. as a better understanding the class has a private query which executes queries in a try..except. then also helper methods: Open, Execute, etc.